# Can I access properties of the HttpPostedFileBase in jQuery validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I'm currently creating some custom attributes for doing uploaded file validation.

One of which is a `FileSizeAttribute` to enforce certain limits (e.g. cannot be bigger than x bytes or smaller than y bytes).

Is there any way I can access the `ContentLength` property of the HttpPostedFileBase? I was reading a tutorial on [file extension validation](http://blog.tomasjansson.com/2011/08/creating-custom-unobtrusive-file-extension-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3-and-jquery/) and the author showed some sample code for simply validating the file extensions.

I'd like to extend to validating the file size client side (in addition to server side) so I can tell them before they even upload if it's outside of the size limits.

From the code snippet available, it seems like he has access to only the filename:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("fileextensions", function (value, element, param) {
    var extension = getFileExtension(value).toLowerCase();
    var validExtension = $.inArray(extension, param.fileextensions) !== -1;
    return validExtension;
});
```

Am I wrong here or am I just missing something? I've never used jQuery and I have a cursory knowledge of JavaScript, so I don't really know if this is even possible.

Comment: no its not, JavaScript is limited in to the browser and has file and OS access restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done if the browser supports the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications). It's a simple matter of querying the `size` property.

Here's an example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class FileExtensionsAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private List<string> ValidExtensions { get; set; }
    public int MaxContentLength { get; set; }

    public FileExtensionsAttribute(string fileExtensions)
    {
        ValidExtensions = fileExtensions.Split('|').ToList();
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (file != null)
        {
            var fileName = file.FileName;
            var isValidExtension = ValidExtensions.Any(y => fileName.EndsWith(y));
            var isValidContentLength = file.ContentLength < MaxContentLength;
            return isValidExtension && isValidContentLength;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ValidationType = "file";
        rule.ErrorMessage = this.FormatErrorMessage(ErrorMessage);
        rule.ValidationParameters["fileextensions"] = string.Join(",", ValidExtensions);
        rule.ValidationParameters["maxcontentlength"] = MaxContentLength.ToString();
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [FileExtensions("txt|doc", MaxContentLength = 200000)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        var getFileExtension = function (fileName) {
            var extension = (/[.]/.exec(fileName)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(fileName) : undefined;
            if (extension != undefined) {
                return extension[0];
            }
            return extension;
        };

        var getFileSize = function (fileElement) {
            if (fileElement.files && fileElement.files.length > 0) {
                return fileElement.files[0].size;
            }
            return -1;
        };

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
            'file', ['fileextensions', 'maxcontentlength'], function (options) {
                var params = {
                    fileextensions: options.params.fileextensions.split(','),
                    maxcontentlength: options.params.maxcontentlength
                };
                options.rules['file'] = params;
                if (options.message) {
                    options.messages['file'] = options.message;
                }
            }
        );

        $.validator.addMethod('file', function (value, element, params) {
            var extension = getFileExtension(value);
            var validExtension = $.inArray(extension, params.fileextensions) !== -1;
            var fileSize = getFileSize(element);
            return validExtension && fileSize < parseInt(params.maxcontentlength);
        }, '');

    })(jQuery);
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.File)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.File)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.File)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/HttpPostedFileBase`):

```
@model HttpPostedFileBase
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, new { type = "file" })
```

Comment: Very cool! Thanks for this. I can at least support client side validation on some browsers then.